# How to use string to represent a variable

Tags: string, actionscript-3, variables

I have a object `e` which has properties like so `e.property1, e.property2, e.property3 ...`

Now I want to use a for loop to trace all the properties. How can I do that?

Something like this is what I am looking for -

```
for(var i:int =0; i<10; i++)
{
    trace(e.property+i); //how do I get the property no. i
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i:* in e) trace(i+" :: "+e[i]);
// if they have to be strings just use ...+e[i].toString();
```

traces

```
property1 :: test
property2 :: 23.3
property3 :: 29
```

using fictional values here

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var s:String in this) trace(this[s]);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but could you maybe write it exactly in accordance with my example. That will help me understand.

Comment: Just filter the results by `s` containing "property".